# Is using the Aura Apex class supported?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, customer-community

When enabling communities in an org, Salesforce adds in some custom lightning components and controllers to help you customize login and registration. These Apex controllers use an **Apex class named `Aura`** to do some redirects. I can't find documentation on this class anywhere (nor is it local to the org). Does anyone know if this class is documented anywhere?

Comment: [Aura Framework documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs)

Comment: Right, that is for the client-side framework. My question is referencing the Apex controllers that make a call to a class named "Aura". I can't find anything Apex related in the documentation. Am I just not looking in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it the developer console.  The auto-complete shows two methods:

`redirect(pageReference)`, as @AH3 pointed out,

and `getComponent()`.

I haven't seen anything documented yet either though.

Answer (score 0):

At this time there seems to be no documentation for the Aura class (System.Aura).

I've tested it and the only method I have available is to do redirects.

```
System.Aura.redirect(pageReference);
```

It may be a new class to interact more easily with lightning components.