# What is aura.redirect?

Tags: lightning, aura, login

I'm looking at one of the custom login controllers for communities and noticed this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl) {

    try{
        ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
        aura.redirect(lgn);
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug('error message ' + ex.getMessage());
        return ex.getMessage();  
    }
}
```

Basically, the user will enter in a username and password, and after they click "login" they will be redirected to the start url. Is there any documentation around aura.redirect?

Comment: i think you are looking for [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm)

Comment: I asked something similar a while back but did not get any good info: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188191/is-using-the-aura-apex-class-supported

Answer (score 8):

No documentation can be found in Salesforce but it just works. The other issue I found is that for some reason test classes don't work well with them. Hence I include code like

`if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
    aura.redirect(lgn);
}`

so that I doesn't affect the test class and code coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately moved away from aura.redirect and used window.location.href to sent the new endpoint. Once the apex controller finished, the callback function in the component redirected the user accordingly.